# Change HTML Select Tag when clicked from many identical elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some functiolality with jQuery to an HTML page but I'm having some troubles with accessing the DOM.
By now,I'm accessing to the DOM elements by 'id' that's because I think is the easiest way to do it but it has a problem. For a unique elemet it's ok but what if I have 2 or more equal elements? Id's supposed to be unique so I need a way diferent to do it.

I have some code which partially does what I need, but as I mentioned before, it only works with "one element", I need to do the same but with 2 or more "equal elements". So let me show you my code so far.

```
<div style="background-color: indigo;">Input
      <select class="" name="" id="ana_dig">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="ana">Analogic</option>
        <option value="dig">Digital</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input" id="dig" style="display:none;">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input" style="display:none;" id="ana">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="0">A0</option>
        <option value="1">A1</option>
        <option value="2">A2</option>
        <option value="3">A3</option>
        <option value="4">A4</option>
        <option value="5">A5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

```
$(function() {
        $('#ana_dig').change(function() {
          $('.input').hide();
          $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
      });
```

As you can see, I have a 'div' which has 3 'select' and depending on what option is selected in the first 'select' it shows you the second or de third 'select'. Pretty easy but if copy and paste de 'div' the second 'div' does not work as the first. What sould I do if I want to 2, 3 or more 'div' work like the first one? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used data attributes as an additional selector.

First we find the parent element enclosing our group of `select` elements. <strike>We then use jQuery [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) function to hide and show</strike>. We can then hide and show using the data attributes.

**NOTE** the id's are unique in the duplicated `div` which is fine. The jQuery below has no dependence on IDs

```js
$("[data-input=type]").on("change", function(){
  //Find the parent that encloses our selects
  var $parent =  $(this).closest(".inputGroup");
  var selValue = $(this).val();
  //Show and hide using toggle()
  //$($parent).find("[data-input=ana]").toggle(selValue === "ana");
  //$($parent).find("[data-input=dig]").toggle(selValue === "dig");
  
  //Don't hide the "type" element - hide the other selects
  $($parent).find("[data-input]").not(this).hide();
  //Show the one with the matching data attribute
  $($parent).find("[data-input= " + selValue + "]").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color: indigo;" class="inputGroup">Input
      <select class="" name="" id="ana_dig" data-input="type">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="ana">Analogic</option>
        <option value="dig">Digital</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input" id="dig" style="display:none;" data-input="dig">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Digital</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input" style="display:none;" id="ana" data-input="ana">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Analog</option>
        <option value="0">A0</option>
        <option value="1">A1</option>
        <option value="2">A2</option>
        <option value="3">A3</option>
        <option value="4">A4</option>
        <option value="5">A5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
<div style="background-color: blue;" class="inputGroup">Input
      <select class="" name="" id="ana_dig2" data-input="type">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="ana">Analogic</option>
        <option value="dig">Digital</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input" id="dig2" style="display:none;" data-input="dig">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Digital</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input" style="display:none;" id="ana2" data-input="ana">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Analog</option>
        <option value="0">A0</option>
        <option value="1">A1</option>
        <option value="2">A2</option>
        <option value="3">A3</option>
        <option value="4">A4</option>
        <option value="5">A5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

With just a little bit of effort we can extend this into dynamically added content. We just need to add one more containing element around the form.

```js
//Event handler is now attatched to [data-input=type] inside 
//formGroup, including any that are dynamically added
$("#formGroup").on("change", "[data-input=type]", function() {
  //Find the parent that encloses our selects
  var $parent = $(this).closest(".inputGroup");
  var selValue = $(this).val();
  //Show and hide using toggle()
  //$($parent).find("[data-input=ana]").toggle(selValue === "ana");
  //$($parent).find("[data-input=dig]").toggle(selValue === "dig");

  //Don't hide the "type" element - hide the other selects
  $($parent).find("[data-input]").not(this).hide();
  //Show the one with the matching data attribute
  $($parent).find("[data-input= " + selValue + "]").show();
});

//Code to add new row
$("#addRow").on("click", function(){
  //Clone first row
  var rowClone = $(".inputGroup").eq(0).clone(true);
  var rowCount = $(".inputGroup").length;
  
  //Change the ids of the nested select elements
  rowClone.find("select").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + rowCount); 
  });
  
  //Append the row 
  $("#formGroup").append(rowClone);
});
```

```css
.inputGroup:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#CCC;
}

.inputGroup {
 padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formGroup">
  <div class="inputGroup">Input
    <select class="" name="" id="ana_dig" data-input="type">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
      <option value="ana">Analogic</option>
      <option value="dig">Digital</option>
    </select>
    <select class="input" id="dig" style="display:none;" data-input="dig">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Digital</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>
    <select class="input" style="display:none;" id="ana" data-input="ana">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Analog</option>
      <option value="0">A0</option>
      <option value="1">A1</option>
      <option value="2">A2</option>
      <option value="3">A3</option>
      <option value="4">A4</option>
      <option value="5">A5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div  class="inputGroup">Input
    <select class="" name="" id="ana_dig2" data-input="type">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
      <option value="ana">Analogic</option>
      <option value="dig">Digital</option>
    </select>
    <select class="input" id="dig2" style="display:none;" data-input="dig">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Digital</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="13">13</option>
    </select>
    <select class="input" style="display:none;" id="ana2" data-input="ana">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Choose Analog</option>
      <option value="0">A0</option>
      <option value="1">A1</option>
      <option value="2">A2</option>
      <option value="3">A3</option>
      <option value="4">A4</option>
      <option value="5">A5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add Another Row" id="addRow"/>
```

Comment: It took me a little bit to figure out what the code does but now I've understood and I could applied to my code. It works fine as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead.

**NOTICE CHANGES NO MORE IDS, CLASS ADDED TO INPUTS YOU CAN HAVE MULTIPLE CLASSES SEPERATED BY SPACE**

```
<div style="background-color: indigo;">Input
      <select class="someclass" name="">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="ana">Analogic</option>
        <option value="dig">Digital</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input dig" style="display:none;">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
      </select>
      <select class="input ana" style="display:none;">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Choose</option>
        <option value="0">A0</option>
        <option value="1">A1</option>
        <option value="2">A2</option>
        <option value="3">A3</option>
        <option value="4">A4</option>
        <option value="5">A5</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

And then do this instead: **SEE THE CHANGE HERE ALSO**

```
$(function() {
        $('.someclass').change(function() {
          $('.input').hide();
          $('.' + $(this).val()).show(); // dot is looking for class # is looking for id
        });
      });
```

Comment: With the information the OPS has provided, this makes sense.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao "but if copy and paste de 'div' the second 'div' does not work as the first." this is the main requirement. This answers dependency on ID fails this.

Comment: My comment was on using class.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao , ahh that clarifies it `class` is certainly a better option than ID. It's a shame the answer still has a dependency on ID which limits its extensibility.

Comment: @JonP The answer does not have dependency on id. Read the entire answer the first div might still have an id but the jquery is using the class for the event.

Comment: @JonP "What sould I do if I want to 2, 3 or more 'div' work like the first one? Any suggestions?" AND also read the entire question

Comment: @EvikGhazarian I have read the entirety of the question and your answer. I fell your answer does not adequately address a duplicate div, with an additional 3 select boxes. Your answer could be improved by demonstrating how it would work with the additional div.

Comment: @JonP Look at the question again. I copied and paste the first div 3 times and the jquery event will still work. Thank you

Comment: OK, so you've copied the first `select` 3 times, from my understanding the OP wants to  copy the entire `<div style="background-color: indigo;">` and its contents multiple times.  - not just adding `selects` to the current `div` .

Comment: @EvikGhazarian I really appreciate your answer but I guess it is not what I was expecting for, maybe I didn't make myself clear, and I'm sorry for that. The fact is that I need to copy the whole "div" and paste it more than 2 times and still have the same functionalty on each one. I also believe a "class" would be better but still don't know how.

Comment: @LuisVázquez Updated my answer now you can copy and paste div as many time as you like

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this hides both the digital, and analog submenus, until it is selected by the first selection:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("select").hide();
     $("#ana_dig").show();
        $("#ana_dig").click(function(){
        var x="#" + $(this).val();
           $("select").hide();
           $("#ana_dig").show();
           $(x).show();
        });
     });
   </script>
```

the op said if they wanted to add more in the first pull down selection, you would just add your additional option element with the value equal to the id to show. I added a reset function so when the first selection is changed, it resets... expanding it only is in the html code too.... I like to use ID for forms, and classes just for styling, and tag names for styling on page events

Comment: The OP wants to duplicate (or more) the enclosing `div` and maintain the functionality. With the reliance on id's `(#ana-dig)`, this approach will not work.

Comment: Id method is the most direct in Jquery. If they need the content dynamic use php to set a number after id name like "ana_dig2"